# c Signal Handler

Tags: c, signals

I am writing an application wherein I want call a function every 1 second. This is what I've written so far

```
Timerspec.it_interval.tv_sec=1;
Timerspec.it_interval.tv_nsec=0;
Timerspec.it_value.tv_sec=1;
Timerspec.it_value.tv_nsec=0;

timer_t timerId;

struct sigaction sa
sa.sa_handler=&TimerFn;
sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL);

timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,NULL,&timerId);
timer_settime(timerId,0,(const itimerspec*)Timerspec,NULL);
```

If my timer function(TimerFn) takes more than 1 second to complete, how to ignore the SIGALRM signals while the handler is running. Please note I want the signal to be ignored only when the handler is running. If handler is not running TimerFn should get called.

Thanks

Comment: `man sigaction(): [...]In addition, the signal  which triggered the handler will be blocked, unless the SA_NODEFER flag is used.[...]`.

Comment: Is that all of your code, with you declaring your `struct sigaction sa` on the stack as a local variable?  If so, it will not be properly initialized and will be filled with undefined contents.  You need to do something like `memset( &sa, 0, sizeof( sa ) );`.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the signal is atomically blocked before entering the handler (unless `SA_NODEFER` is used), and unblocked after returning from the handler, so there's nothing you need to do.

The way you declare and use `sa` is buggy: you need to at least initialize the `sa_flags` field to 0, and you need to initialize the `sa_mask` field to the empty signal set:

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = &TimerFn;
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL);
```

Note that the signal being caught is always blocked upon entering the handler and unblocked when leaving, even if you specified an empty signal mask in the `sa_mask` field of `struct sigaction`.

Comment: `[...]unless the SA_NODEFER flag is used.[...]`. Am I repeating myself?

Comment: @EOF True. I was just saying he doesn't have to worry about it with this code, because `SA_NODEFER` is not the default behavior. Anyway, I updated my answer with this detail.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Filipe Thanks for the answer